# Loop increase number

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query, functions, loop

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'order' => 'ASC',
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"ItemList",
      "itemListElement":[
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        {
          "@type":"ListItem",
          "position":1,
          "url":"<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
        },
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      ]
    }
    </script>
```

I am putting a schematic to display a Carousels, but it is required to place the `"position": 1`

I need help for the loop to increase the number 1. "position": **1**

also remove last comma from last post

Answer (score 1):

You can add a php variable and increment it every time the while loop runs

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'events',
  'order' => 'ASC',
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"ItemList",
      "itemListElement":[
      <?php 
        $i=0;
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $i++; ?>
        {
          "@type":"ListItem",
          "position":"<?php echo $i; ?>",
          "url":"<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
        },
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      ]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it does not generate anything, if I delete,  $i=0 and $i++; .. yes, but no working increase the number

Comment: It needs to be `<?php echo $i; ?>`, the rest of the answer is correct

Comment: @kero still no work :/

Comment: add for ($n = 0; $n <= 7; $n++) and <?php echo ($n + 1) ?> and work

Comment: This will fail if you have more than 7 items returned. You could store $wp_query->post_count in a variable and run the loop accordingly

Comment: How remove last comma? },

Comment: try json_encode($array) that will make sure the format is correct removing the last comma

Answer (score 1):

```
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'events',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":"http://schema.org",
      "@type":"ItemList",
      "itemListElement":[
      <?php
        $comma = ",";
        $i=0;
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $i++;
        ?>

        {
          "@type":"ListItem",
          "position":"<?php echo $i; ?>",
          "url":"<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
        }<?php if($i!=5){
          echo $comma;
        }?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      ]
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: why repeat number ..now show 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 :/ @sneha-agarwal

Comment: ready! working perfect!